# Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics

Tags: javascript

Jshint ругается на то, что в функции есть ссылки на внешние переменные. Если их убрать, то перестаёт ругаться. Но у меня 1 переменная константная, а вторая глобальная Array(которая часть самого языка либо официально рекомендуемых библиотек).   То есть это статические данные и функции. Как это можно решить средствами es5?

```
var name = 'ivan';

           srtOpt.sortFunc = function(a, b) {
            var val_a = a[name];
            var val_b = b[name];

            if (Array.isArray(val_a)) {

            }
            ...
           }
```

Comment: а на какую конкретно строчку/строчки ругается jshint?

Comment: больше похоже, что твой код выполняется в цикле, и именно в этом проблема

Comment: Да, внутри цикла был вызов. Сейчас вынес из него и перестал ругаться.

Comment: Добавь исходный код в вопрос